# Reset usercontrol placed on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Probably simple question but couldn't find any working solution. I have User control on windows form. I would like on button click placed on user control to reload user control. By reload i mean to reset all its variables and show again. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that does that. You could dispose the existing control and create a new one but noone would do that. Basically, it's a manual process. If you want the control's fields reset to defaults then you need to write code to do that. You might declare a `Reset` method and put all the code in there if that's appropriate and then you can simply call that method from the form.